# Perl Net::Telnet::Cisco Bad named parameter

Tags: perl, parameters

I'm trying to get some scripting finished to deploy changes en masse to about 400 Cisco devices. I've got a perl script modified from [MrAudit](http://blog.alwaysthenetwork.com/useful-links/great-perl-script/) that's using [Net::Telnet::Cisco](http://search.cpan.org/~joshua/Net-Telnet-Cisco-1.10/Cisco.pm) and for the life of me, I can't figure out the named parameter component.

In the documentation, they have:

```
$ok = $obj->cmd($string);
$ok = $obj->cmd(String   => $string,
                [Output  => $ref,]
                [Prompt  => $match,]
                [Timeout => $secs,]
                [Cmd_remove_mode => $mode,]);

@output = $obj->cmd($string);
@output = $obj->cmd(String   => $string,
                    [Output  => $ref,]
                    [Prompt  => $match,]
                    [Timeout => $secs,]
                    [Cmd_remove_mode => $mode,]
                    [Normalize_cmd => $boolean,]);
```

And my code is:

$testString is the test command I'm running against the device, $userTest1 is an array being cast where I want the output to be stored.

```
$::OPENRTR->cmd(String=>$testString,[Timeout=>5,Output=>$userTest1,]);
```

And every single time, no matter which component I modify or try and write it a different way, I get a variation of the error:

```
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at(filename)
bad named parameter "ARRAY(0x2e46460)" given to Net::Telnet::Cisco::cmd() at mrAudit-TACACSMod.pl line 279
```

I know it has to be something simple, but it's just flying right by. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your `$obj` actually the global `$OPENRTR` in the `main` namespace and you are calling it from a different package? Why?!

Comment: Those error messages are two different errors. You cut the line off the first one with _odd number of elements_. Do you have `use strict` and `use warnings` in your code?

Comment: The object in the global is based on the original script, I didn't write it, just using it so I don't have to re-write the wheel.

And use warnings is in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the square brackets in the documentation just show the arguments are optional, you shouldn't use them in real code:

```
 $OPENRTR->cmd( String  => $testString,
                Timeout => 5,
                Output  => $userTest1);
```

Comment: It was hard to see from the documentation as code in the question. (facepalm)

Comment: In fact OP used them wrong. They did `cmd( foo => "bar", [ baz => "qux", "asd" => "fgh" ] )` and not `cmd( foo => "bar", [ baz => "qux"], ["asd" => "fgh" ] )` as the _docs suggested_.

Comment: I had tried that format as well, and it didn't work.

Comment: @choroba What simbabque suggested, by placing each optional parameter in separate '[]' statements. It looks like yours is working now, feel like an idiot to include them altogether.

Comment: @DavisTasar: I'd probably submit a bugreport for the documentation.